# Reasons for tooth-base sensitivity?

Tags: dentistry, pain, oral-health, toothpaste

**What are the possible reasons for sensitivity of tooth bases to heat, cold, or sweet?**

(I am not referring to gum pain, but pain in the actual teeth at the base at/below the gum line.)

In my reading, I have found that people experience sensitivity in a tooth after having a tooth treated by a dentist with filling work etc.

**However, I've also encountered situations where the treatment of gum retreat at the base line of teeth with a rinse has the same sensitivity on other teeth, including untreated ones!**

Comment: @Narusan: Having read the linked meta post, I fail to understand why this question was marked as off-topic. The "personal" level of its advice-seeking is really no more personal than that of most other questions here. Also, a highly-voted answer in that meta post reads that even personal advice questions are ok, as long as "[1] it does not require seeing a doctor; [2] it is useful to others", conditions that it seems to me my question meets, since other dental patients might well have the same experience and question. Either way, happy to edit the question if more useful feedback can be left.

Comment: Hi @z8080, welcome to Health.SE.  Thanks for reading about it, that's great that you looked into it!  We are in the process of narrowing down what medical advice is.  That meta is 2 yrs old, we should update it. Check this one here:  https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor

Comment: So let me help you.  Adding your experience makes it more like individualized advice. I proposed an edit that makes it more answerable for site guidelines.  You can revert it or edit it if you disagree!  See edit history for that.

Comment: @Narusan do you think this is an okay edit? Assuming the OP approves and doesn't revert it, I think this is answerable.

Comment: Haven't seen a notification for some reason... @DoctorWhom Yes, I'd definitely reopen that, but I don't have my laptop near me and you can't do that on the mobile app... Update: Voted to reopen

Comment: @DoctorWhom: many thanks for your help! The edit looks fine, except that the focus of my question is not so much on the possible causes of tooth-base sensitivity (far too broad a question for me interest), but really on why this sensitivity would appear after each and every dentist visit, even when no teeth were actually treated. If you like, feel free to edit the question to reflect this (as a moderator); or equally, I can have a go.

Comment: @z8080 What do you think of my edit? Does this suite you? A thought: It might also be related to the placebo effect if 4 teeth are treated and hurt and the others hurt as well.

Comment: @Narusan lol editing at the same time :) I like yours better.

Comment: For @z8080, you're welcome!  I recognize that you want to know that about it happening after the dentist, but you didn't specify if they did any cleaning at all, just that they poked at a tooth with a filling and blew air it.  What else did they do?  Did they use any rinses or chemicals? That could be incorporated into a general (non-personal) question as well.

Comment: Agreed with @DoctorWhom. We don't really have a starting point to try to explain what might cause the sensitivity without details of what actions you are referring to. The problem with personal diagnosis is that we can tell you why something might have happened, but we tend to close those questions as soon as they get too personal. So including information "if one was to get rinses" is fine, but "I got x rinses and y and this is the result" will be closed.

Comment: [cont'd] It is difficult with the close reasons, and it will take some time for your question to be reopened because we don't have many high-rep users sadly. I did my share, and we'll have to wait now. Welcome, by the way.

Comment: The edit looks fine, thank you. More information about the treatment I received would indeed help with my receiving a relevant answer, but that might contravene with the 'too personal' policy (over which it makes no sense to debate here). That treatment did not include an actual cleaning but did include applying some chemicals to a (restricted) part of my gums. That I can now barely brush my teeth without pain I doubt very much is a placebo (but then who wouldn't doubt that what they experience is merely a placebo? :) )

Comment: @z8080 [Let's Continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65066/discussion-about-z8080s-post)

Comment: @michaelpri Would you mind reconsidering your close vote, as the question has been sufficiently edited (in my eyes)?

Comment: @Narusan Edits are definitely sufficient. Thanks

Comment: One thing you might want to consider is *referred pain*.